# How to run a Trivy scan on Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, security, docker-image, trivy

In the [installation page](https://aquasecurity.github.io/trivy/v0.19.2/getting-started/installation/) for Trivy there is no mention of Windows.

I have Docker for Windows installed so the Docker method looks promising but there are a couple of things I'm not sure of:

1. What should I set the cache directory to?
2. Will I need to "mount docker.sock"? And if so, will I need to replace the `/var/run` and `$HOME/Library/Caches` directories in that command with something more "Windows-ey"?

The aim is to scan an image that I built using Docker for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of release 0.36.0 (30 Dec 2022), trivy is now available as a Windows EXE.

You can find the latest release in the [Releases directory](https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy/releases). Expand it to show the full list of files and then scroll down until you find a filename of the form `trivy_x.yy.z_windows-64bit.zip`. Download the file and unzip it on your PC. Look for the executable `trivy.exe`.

Answer (score 6):

1. Install Docker for Windows
2. Install Git Bash
3. Open a Git Bash Shell on Windows
4. Execute the command: `docker pull aquasec/trivy:0.19.2`
5. `docker run --rm -v C:\Users\<your foldername>:/root/.cache/ aquasec/trivy:0.19.2 aquasec/trivy:0.19.2 python:3.4-alpine`
6. The scan will start to run. It may take a few minutes to return any response.

Comment: the documentaiton mentions about having to mount docker.sock. How does that translate to running trivy in windows? https://aquasecurity.github.io/trivy/v0.22.0/getting-started/installation/

Answer (score 4):

With Docker Deskttop for windows installed you can open a terminal (recomended powershell for the next command).

```html
docker run --rm -v ${PWD}/tmp:/root/.cache/ -v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  aquasec/trivy <image>
```

You can use your actual path with this command. It´s better than use absolute paths. Also, you can mount the docker socket to trivy to scan your downloaded images.

Answer (score 2):

Basically I don't think this is achievable for this exact scenario. The closest way around is to run trivy in WSL, but that isn't technically running on Windows directly.

https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy/issues/1103

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Go (https://go.dev/doc/install)
2. Pull Trivy and go in the pulled directory

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch v0.32.0 https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy
cd trivy
```

3. Install Trivy

`go install .\cmd\trivy`

Comment: No luck with this method:
```no required module provides package .cmdtrivy;```

Comment: @kdlannoy if you are running from a bash shell in Windows you'll need to escape the '\', so `go install .\\cmd\\trivy`

Answer (score 0):

First, I used the WSL to scan the windows containers.
Last, I used the go compiler to build a trivy.exe.

Both of these 2 ways work well.

Answer (score 0):

Able to run the scan by running the below command for manifest scanning:

docker run --rm -v C:/projects/abc:/test aquasec/trivy:latest --exit-code 0 --severity UNKNOWN,LOW,MEDIUM,HIGH,CRITICAL --format template --template "@contrib/html.tpl" -o /test/manifest-scanning-report.html config /test/k8s_dir

This will generate a manifest-scanning-report.html under C:/projects folder.

Answer (score -1):

The above answer is bit outdated. Here is the correct one with slight modification.

Open a Git Bash Shell on Windows Execute the commands below:

1. `docker pull aquasec/trivy:latest`
2. `docker run --rm -v [YourLocalDir]:/root/.cache/ aquasec/trivy:latest [COMMAND_TO_RUN] [YOUR_IMAGE_NAME]`

E.g. If you want to run a scan on a docker image then run below command.

`docker run --rm -v ./:/root/.cache/ aquasec/trivy:latest image ubuntu:22.04`

You can scan filesystem,kubernetes and other things also by changing the COMMAND_TO_RUN.
Reference Doc: https://aquasecurity.github.io/trivy/v0.22.0/getting-started/cli/